# delete datasets in azure

Tags: azure, cloud, powerbi-embedded

I am new to Power BI.Basically through API i'm creating the collection,workspace and dataset. Initially i struggled lot to understand this.But now i have done dataset and everything.Now i have to delete all the dataset which i have created.

i have refered the documentation.But i could not get.

http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io

I am using https://portal.azure.com. There also i could not find datasets in the portal.
Please help me.

Comment: can you show us the abi you used to create the dataset?

Comment: this is the abi i used https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/NewYork/workspaces/fd5dde55-8d06-4a24-baff-d253e6084f4b/datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workspace Collection Deletion:**

A **Workspace** is a container of Power BI content, which can include **datasets** and reports. A Workspace is empty when first created.In portal.azure.com you can search the Power BI workspace collection.Then It will list out the workspace. when you will click the workspace that will show you their properties in right side with delete icon.You can use that to delete.

[image]

If you want to delete the workspace through API refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/powerbiembedded/workspacecollections#WorkspaceCollections_delete)

**Dataset Deletion:**

When you delete the dataset that will delete their report which has been connected to it.You can use the following request to delete the dataset.

```
DELETE https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/{collectionName}/workspaces/{workspaceId}/datasets/{datasetKey}/
```

DELETE-Request method.

In your case

```
DELETE https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/NewYork/workspaces/fd5dde55-8d06-4a24-baff-d253e6084f4b/datasets/your_datasetid
```

For more information check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt711493.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much.This is what i want.